# How can i change in VBA the custom format of a cell to Generic "randomtext"?

Tags: vba, excel

If i change it manually it works.

If then i run this:

```
Sub cellformat()  
  ShowCellFormat = Range("A1").NumberFormat  
  MsgBox ShowCellFormat  
  Range("A2").NumberFormat = ShowCellFormat  
End Sub
```

this works too, msgbox displays:

> Generic "randomtext"

The only thing that i cant manage is to change the format like this:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Generic "randomtext""
```

Tried 100 different ways still not working...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want your number format to be something like `"XYZ"0000"DEF"` to display the number `15` as `XYZ0015DEF`, then you can't write your code as

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = ""XYZ"0000"DEF""
'or
'Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Generic "randomtext""
```

You instead need to write the code as:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = """XYZ""0000""DEF"""
'or
'Range("A1").NumberFormat = "Generic ""randomtext"""
```

because each double-quotation mark (i.e. `"`) used within a string literal needs to be escaped by writing it as `""`.